# Loadfile, specific lines from .txt file into array

Tags: python, arrays, file-io

I have a .txt file and I need to open it and create an array (in Python).  However, I do not want to select all the lines for the array, everything but the first line.

For example, my .txt file reads:

```
 1 1 1
 1 4 6
 4 5 6
 8 9 7
```

and, I would like to create an array such that, I can assign it like:

```
 Y= array([[1, 4, 6], [4, 5, 6], [8, 9, 7]])
```

I need to generalize it for future files that will create an array that omits first line of text.

Comment: What have you done so far?  Make sure you post your code - not only does it help us understand what you're doing, but it makes it easier to give you advice.  It's also a courtesy, since it shows that you've made an effort first before asking others to make an effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
with open(file) as f:
    Y = [map(int, line.split()) for line in f.readlines()[1:]]
```

Notice the `[1:]` which grabs all the other lines except for the first one.

Comment: @ashwinlyengar, if I want to grab every line except for the first and the last (number of lines vary for each text file), how would I do this? (for future reference)

Comment: If you have an array called ``a``, you just do ``a[1:-1]``. The python format for array indexing is ``[start:stop:step]`` (all optional), so you can specify where to start, stop, and then how many elements to skip (e.g. ``a[::2]`` gives you every second element of ``a``). Furthermore, a negative index specifies the number of elements from the back of the array. This is why ``[1:-1]`` works: it essentially means "every element from the first element to the second to last element."

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import numpy

data = numpy.loadtxt('data.txt',skiprows=1)
```

Comment: See more options at [{here}](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: if I want to skip the first and third row as well, how do I do this?  Thanks. For future reference

Comment: @har.cruz1972 For complete flexibility you may use the above method and `slicing`. For example, with above you can ignore any number of lines from the beginning. Then for the rest of your work e.g., skipping 3rd row etc it is better use `slice`. For example, `data = numpy.vstack(data[:2],data[3:])`. More flexibility can be achieved using `masking`. `msk = numpy.ones((data.shape[0],))`, `msk[2] = 0`, `data = data[msk]`. See in this way any complexity is easy to handle.